# NullReferenceException was unhandled VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, search, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to assign to an array a record that has to be split into more elements for search criteria reasons. For example, if criteria is set to First Name, then search for matching keyword in array element 0 because that's where first name will be placed after the currently selected record is Split().

Source for the search form:

```
Public Class frmSearch
    Dim arrayCurrentRecord(6) As String
    Private Sub btnCancel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
        'fill array with list box items
        Dim arraySearch(frmMain.numberOfRecords) As String
        For i = 0 To frmMain.numberOfRecords - 1
            arraySearch(i) = frmMain.lstListBox.Items(i)
        Next i

        If rbtnFirstName.Checked = True Then
            For i = 0 To UBound(arraySearch)
                arrayCurrentRecord = arraySearch(i).Split(" ")
                If InStr(arrayCurrentRecord(0), txtSearch.Text) = True Then
                    lstSearch.Items.Add(arraySearch(i))
                End If
            Next i
            MsgBox("search complete")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing `For i = 0 To UBound(arraySearch)` to
`For i = 0 To UBound(arraySearch) - 1` fixed the issue, but it won't find anything just says that search was complete.

Answer (score -1):

Changing line

```
If InStr(arrayCurrentRecord(0), txtSearch.Text) = True
```

to

```
If InStr(arrayCurrentRecord(0), txtSearch.Text)
```

resolved the problem.